# NSSwitchCell doesn't change value after clicking it

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've bound a NSSwitchCells column to a NSArrayController. The values ON/OFF are correctly displayed, however when I click on it, the value doesn't change. The switch box gives visual feedback of the clicking but the value remains the same (checked or unchecked).

[image]

I've tried all sort of binding options.

```
 NSDictionary *bindingOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption, 
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], NSValidatesImmediatelyBindingOption,

                                                nil];
                [tableColumn bind:@"value" toObject:currentItemsArrayController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", editedColumnmetadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];   

[(NSButtonCell*)cell setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
                [cell setTitle:@""];
                [tableColumn setDataCell:cell];
```

thanks

UPDATE: (binding to the cell ?)

```
 //[tableColumn bind:@"value" toObject:currentItemsArrayController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", editedColumnmetadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
 [cell bind:@"objectValue" toObject:currentItemsArrayController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", editedColumnmetadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
```

Comment: Did you bind your table column checkbox cell on to your arraycontroller?

Comment: @hussainShabbir I haven't. How should I bind it exactly ? I've added the code to my question. If I uncomment the line tableColumn the buttons are disabled, I can't interact with them. The second line, the bind to the cell, doesn't change anything in the current behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow below steps and let me know if you required some more details:-

First you have to bind your column of checkbox cell to arraycontroller inside binding inspector as attached in the screenshots below.

[image]

Second thing in your array controller if you want to update the value of checkbox cell then write this below action method and connect this action method to your table column of  checkbox cell only.

```
-(IBAction)clickChekBoxcell:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger chkCell=[sender integerValue];
    NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:chkCell];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(dict in [arrCont arrangedObjects])
    {
        [dict setObject:num forKey:@"checkYesNo"];
    }
    [arrCont rearrangeObjects];
}
```